# Error when launching the storyboard in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, storyboard, visual-studio-2019

When ever I click on launchscreen.storyboard I get the following error message, it works sometimes so I am not sure what is causing this. I have tried creating a new project and reinstalling visual studio and it hasn't worked.

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Error in the application.
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest(CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 235
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse](CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 252
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession() in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 111
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0() in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 116
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<>c__DisplayClass289_1`1.<EnsureSession>b__1(Task`1 t) in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 2070
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<>c__DisplayClass289_0`1.<EnsureSession>b__0() in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 2136
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<RenderXmlWithPartialReloadRetry>d__191.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 745
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<RenderXmlWithPartialReloadRetry>d__191.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 752
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<RenderXml>d__190.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 730
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<RenderXml>d__190.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 738
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<ReloadItemsAsync>d__186.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 619
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Tasks.<Cancellable>d__1.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Shared\TaskExtensions.cs:line 28
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<ReloadItems>d__185.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 571
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Error in the application.
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest(CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 235
```

Comment: Did you update your XCode to the latest stable version with the latest Visual-Studio version?

Comment: Add more details about your XCode and VS!

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes

Comment: You can report it inside Visual-Studio, send feedback--> report a problem.